# Braintree Cancel button handling

Tags: iphone, swift, paypal-sandbox, braintree

Just use sandbox mode and press on Pay button after entering the details. once the payment is started processing, press cancel button immediately. This will call the cancel method where we are calling dismissViewController but at the same time after dismissing the payment view payment succeed delegate is also called. And we have nothing there to check whether fail or success or something else. Also i have tried to take class reference and set it to nil in cancel delegate. Help me if anyone faced the same.

Comment: Do you need to do **cancel**, after clicking **PAY**..?

Comment: No. I am searching for some method which get called when someone click pay so that i can remove cancel from there.